# How to create a calculated Row in an unpivoted table?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose we have the following the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Values](
    [Style Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Trim Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Report Year] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Accounts] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Value] [decimal](25, 10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

with the following sample data:

```
Style Code  Trim Code   Report Year Accounts        Value
Car         blue1       2019        EBIT            -234.98
Car         blue1       2019        Administrative  87773.01
Car         blue1       2019        Net Sales       9000.9
Truck       green       2020        EBIT            7653.02
Truck       green       2020        Administrative  -9345
Truck       green       2020        Net Sales        6544
```

We have an Accounts table in which Account serves as PK for the Accounts column in Values table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts](
    [Account] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Accounts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Account] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Values]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Accounts] FOREIGN KEY([Accounts])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Accounts] ([Account])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Values] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Accounts]
```

The Account column holds the following data:

```
Account
Administrative
EBIT
Net Sales
```

These tables are used to build an SSAS Tabular cube. we visualize this cube data in Excel.

so it looks something like this:

[image: Excel]

We have a requirement to calculate `%EBIT = EBIT/Net Sales`

If the table was pivoted, this would be easily added as a calculated column. However, the requirement is `%EBIT` MUST be a row, just like the rest of the Accounts are. In other words, it has to be a dynamic calculation.

Since creating `%EBIT` as a calculated column is not the option/solution, how do we create a ***calculated row***? is it possible? and if so, how do we approach this?

---

Update: Pivoted Values Table version:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PivotedValues]
AS
(SELECT
  [Style Code],
  [Trim Code],
  [Report Year],
  COALESCE([Administrative], 0) [Administrative], --Convert NULLs to 0's
  COALESCE([Net Sales], 0) [Net Sales],
  COALESCE([EBIT], 0) [EBIT]
FROM Values 
    PIVOT (SUM([Value]) FOR [Accounts] IN (
        [Administrative], 
        [Net Sales],
        [EBIT]
        )
    ) 
AS PivotedValues);
```

Comment: The `Accounts` table has one column `Account` with four data elements inside it?

Comment: @LarsSkaug yes (well actually 3 data here EBIT, Administrative and Net Sales)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is via a self join to the same table.

have a look at this solution :

```
; with my_data as (

select 

'Car' as style_code    ,    'blue1'    as trim_code ,  2019 as report_year   ,    'EBIT'    accounts   ,     -234.98 value

union all select

'Car', 'blue1'   ,    2019    ,    'Administrative' , 87773.01
union all select
'Car',  'blue1'   ,    2019  ,      'Net Sales'   ,    9000.9
union all select
'Truck', 'green'   ,    2020  ,      'EBIT'    ,        7653.02
union all select
'Truck', 'green'    ,   2020  ,      'Administrative',  -9345
union all select
'Truck', 'green'     ,  2020  ,      'Net Sales'  ,      6544

)
,ebit as (
Select
my_data.*
 ,case when my_data.accounts = 'Net Sales' and isnull(ebit_calc.value,0)<>0  
    then ebit_calc.value /my_data.value 
        else null end as [%EBIT]

from my_data

left join my_data ebit_calc
        on ebit_calc.style_code = my_data.style_code
            and ebit_calc.trim_code = my_data.trim_code
            and ebit_calc.report_year = my_data.report_year
            and ebit_calc.accounts = 'EBIT'

    
    )

    Select 
    style_code
    ,trim_code
    ,report_year
    ,accountss
    ,EBIT
    
    from ebit

    unpivot
    (
    EBIT
    for accountss in ([%EBIT])
    ) as ebits
 

 union all

 select my_data.* from 

 my_data

 order by style_code,trim_code,report_year
```

Yet another way to do this without using UNION

```
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF


; with my_data as (

select 

'Car' as style_code    ,    'blue1'    as trim_code ,  2019 as report_year   ,    'EBIT'    accounts   ,     -234.98 value

union all select

'Car', 'blue1'   ,    2019    ,    'Administrative' , 87773.01
union all select
'Car',  'blue1'   ,    2019  ,      'Net Sales'   ,    9000.90
union all select
'Truck', 'green'   ,    2020  ,      'EBIT'    ,        7653.02
union all select
'Truck', 'green'    ,   2020  ,      'Administrative',  -9345.00
union all select
'Truck', 'green'     ,  2020  ,      'Net Sales'  ,      6544.00

)

,pivoting as (

SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
     style_code
    ,trim_code
    ,report_year
    ,cast(value as decimal(13,2)) as value
    ,accounts
    FROM 
        my_data        
) t 
PIVOT(
    sum(value) 
    FOR accounts IN (
        EBIT, 
        Administrative, 
        [Net Sales] )
) AS pivot_table

)

,calc as (
Select 
pivoting.style_code
,pivoting.report_year
,cast(pivoting.Administrative as decimal(13,2)) as Administrative
,cast(pivoting.EBIT as decimal(13,2))  as EBIT
,cast(pivoting.[Net Sales] as decimal(13,2)) [Net Sales]
,pivoting.trim_code
,cast( EBIT/[Net Sales] as decimal(13,2)) as [Ebit_percent]

from pivoting

)



Select 

    style_code
    ,trim_code
    ,report_year
    ,Amounts
    ,Accounts
    
    from calc

    unpivot
    (
    Amounts 
    for [Accounts] in (EBIT, Administrative, [Net Sales],[Ebit_percent])
    ) as ebits
```

Comment: but this one gives %EBIT as calculated column. We are looking to create %EBIT as a calculated ROW, just like Administrative, EBIT, and Net Sales Accounts

Comment: Please see updated code.. it's a bit of a hack job.. but it works.. I think

Comment: I think this does the trick :) However, since our table is very large, has over million records, its gonna be rediculous to union every single row lol. do you know how i can look through each row instead of doing this `union all select`? or you only did that for the case of creating a temp table `my_data`?

Comment: there might be a better way, but it gives you an idea of how to achieve this if not the exact solution. Only work with what we can see from the question you ask. The context of implementing the solution however lies in your hands ;)

Comment: Oh wait are you just union all selecting because my_data is a temporary table in this case so you are unionizing the records as you insert them? If that's the case, then we already have thr table filled with the data rows so we dont have to do union all select on each row since they are already inserted in the table, right?

Comment: well,, I guess another way to look at this would be to pivot all your accounts.. derive the calculated column and then unpivot all the columns

Comment: Oh yes, I actually did this using views because we had to unionize 2 tables with data (one pivoted and one unpivoted). So I do have a pivoted table. Suppose i do, and I post the sql in my post, could you provide another option using it to derive the column as you mention? I would like to share the 2 options tomorrow with the business so I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: please see my updated post of the pivoted version of the Values table

Comment: See my answer edits.. have added another way to do the same

Comment: Nice! Thank you. btw, i think there was some confusion earlier. I thought I had to also use union all select for each row but i just realized that you were only doing that because you were inserting into a temp table using WITH. in my case, that section is unnecessary cause i already have the data inserted. I will follow up with business tomorrow and update you on what they think :)

Comment: whichever way you look at it.. the solutions work. would appreciate an accepted answer if it does the job

Comment: of course, i upvoted and accepted. I will comment back tomorrow to report business opinion. would you be around to engage in case they want a certain modification?